# Extract topic word probability matrix in gensim LdaModel

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have the LDA model and the document-topic probabilities.

```
# build the model on the corpus
ldam = LdaModel(corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary) 
# get the document-topic probabilities
theta, _ = ldam.inference(corpus)
```

I also need the distribution of words for all the topics i.e. a topic-word probability matrix. Is there a way to extract this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topics-term matrix (lambda) is accessible via :

```
topics_terms = ldam.state.get_lambda()
```

If you want a probability distribution just normalize it :

```
topics_terms_proba = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x/x.sum(),1,topics_terms)
```

Comment: when I use `ldam.state.get_lambda()` I get a numpy matrix but the there are no column names. How do I identify the words?

Comment: To know which word corresponds to a given index, use `ldam.id2word`. For example `ldam.id2word[0]` is the word corresponding to the first column of the matrix.